# Unable to mock an exported named function with jest / react-testing-library whilst rendering a nextjs page

Tags: next.js, jestjs, mocking, react-testing-library

I've been trying to mock a named imported function in a NextJS page but all attempts I've gleaned from various sites have failed so far.

I've tried to reproduce this using `create-next-app` with `--example with-jest` minimal code as follows.

My `pages/index.tsx` :

```
import Head from 'next/head'
import { hello } from '../utils/greeter'

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <title>Create Next App</title>
      </Head>

      <main>
        <h1>{hello()}</h1>
      </main>
    </div>
  )
}
```

I then have my `utils/greeter.ts` containing the named exported function I'd like to be able to mock/spyOn within the test cases

```
export const hello = (): string => 'hello world';
```

Finally the test file `__tests__/index.test.tsx`:

```
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react'
import Home from '@/pages/index'

describe('Home', () => {
  it('renders unmocked greeting', () => {
    render(<Home />)

    const heading = screen.getByRole('heading', {
      name: 'hello world',
    })

    expect(heading).toBeInTheDocument()
  })
  it('renders mocked greeting', () => {
    render(<Home />)

    const heading = screen.getByRole('heading', {
      name: 'hello mock',
    })

    expect(heading).toBeInTheDocument()
  })
})
```

I can change the mock implementation via adding the following above my test cases:

```
jest.mock('../utils/greeter', () => ({
  __esModule: true,
  hello: () => 'hello mock'
})
```

This will correctly alter the function and cause the 2nd test case to pass but the mock exists for all test cases so causes the 1st test case to fail.

I'd love to be able to choose for each test case whether I'd like to use the real implementation, a mock implementation, and even leverage a spy to allow for verification of what the mock function was called with for example.

Any time I try to replace the 'hello mock' string being returned with a reference, such as

```
const mockFn = jest.fn()
```

And then in each test case try to override the return value, e.g.

```
mockFn.mockReturnValue('hello mock')
```

Both tests fail as it appears the `hello()` function isn't returning the mocked values.

I've also seen instances of people suggesting to use [`jest.spyOn(..)`](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname) but the function isn't part of an object, so can't get past the type errors with this one.

Any pointers where I maybe going wrong or mis-understanding the jest mocking process would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a sample sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/so-76946742-unable-to-mock-an-exported-named-function-with-jest-74ncpr) with both tests passing.

There are two key elements you need:

1. First, you need to mock the module itself, using a mock function (`jest.fn()`) for `hello`.

```js
jest.mock("../utils/greeter", () => ({
  __esModule: true,
  hello: jest.fn(() => "hello world"),
}));
```

2. Then, in tests where you want `hello()` to return a different value, you need to override it with one of the `.mock*Once()` functions. The `jest.mocked()` function doesn't do anything on its own; it simply returns the input object, but it asserts it as a mocked type so that TypeScript knows about its `.mock*()` functions. It does not do any mocking itself, so there will be errors if it is not properly mocked.

```js
jest.mocked(hello).mockReturnValueOnce("hello mock");
```